# Play framework lib folder issue

Tags: playframework

I'm developing a play framework application and using SBT to build the application and run

I have my external libraries in project/lib folder. I want to run as well as create an executable exe or jar for production deployment

```
for deployment, we can use sbt dist
for running, we can use sbt run
for compiling, we can use sbt compile
```

However the project is being compiled successfully via sbt compile and the project is run with sbt run. However when application runs, the classed gets loaded, huge errors comes because the library added in lib folder is not taken into deployment or in the bundle

```
#1 - How to add the lib/jar to deployment ?
#2 - How to add the lib/jar when running in IDE, do we need to have 2 versions, just 
     add the library manually and during commit, remove the library as it should be 
     added manually
```

What is the best practice on this context?

Thanks